# Error:Invalid Argument

Tags: c++

I'm having issue in this line of code

```
GsmMeasurements * gsm_measurements = new GsmMeasurements(*(request->get_mr()));
```

and the error is:

assing ‘const Request’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘virtual gfp::MeasurementReport* Request::get_mr()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

prototype of GsmMeasurements is

```
GsmMeasurements(const gfp::MeasurementReport& mr);
```

prototype of get_mr is

```
gfp::MeasurementReport* RequestA::get_mr ( )
```

`RequestA` inheriting `Request`

I'm unable to understand why this error is coming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gfp::MeasurementReport* RequestA::get_mr ( )` needs to be changed to

`gfp::MeasurementReport* RequestA::get_mr ( ) const`

This is because `request` is a pointer to a constant object, so any function needs to be marked `const`.

Your question text is so comprehensive that, I believe, this can be the *only* possibility.

Comment: why? we don't care if the method is const, we want the result to be const, arent we?

Comment: The compiler cares very much: you can't call a non-constant function using a constant pointer.